# position relative/absolute issue in html mail

Tags: html, css, email

I am recently trying to send html mails but i am facing some issues with div position. relative/absolute.I tried to Google and found that positioning of div in not supported in email clients.

What i really wanted to do is..I have a image as below.[image: original image]

Now I need to draw a rectangle on the Image through html.What i have is just position of the rectangle on the image.Suppose for some coordinated it is on the house.Same as like below image
[image: new image]

Can any one help??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: it can be done by position: absolute  and after that just use the right:0 and top:300 or 400 just use acc to the distance

Comment: To be honest you'll struggle in a lot of email clients with this

Answer (score 1):

You can go for absolute positioning.I have written the sample code here. Please refer this link http://jsfiddle.net/shivkumarganesh/Fga2z/

Yeah table will also be efficient!

```
.table{
background:url('your image URL');
background-width:300px;
background-height:200px;
width:300px;
height:200px;
background-repeat:no-repeat"
}

<table class="table">
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
<!--Now make TD and TR tags and give them Custom height so that at least one cell is on the image.Then give that cell <td> a border eg.border:red 2px solid.-->
```

Comment: no position attribute supported for div in email clients..any other option??may be from table

Comment: @Parth I have edited my previous answer hope this would guide you for whatever effect you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't figure out why you're css doesn't work in the email you might wanna try using inline styles only. In the past I've found that some email clients seem to ignore classes and certain rules within the internal style sheets. the only thing that works properly are inline styles and tags such as B.

Comment: +1 many email clients strip out style blocks, that said, I think support for positioning is pretty spotty.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience position absolute should be ok to use.

just make sure you add at least `position: relative` to the container in which you want to position the rectangle. otherwise it'll be positioned absolute to the document body.

something like this should do the trick:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="rectangle"></div>
   <img src="....">
</div>

.container{
  position:relative;
}

.rectangle{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px; 
  border: 2px solid red;
```

}

Comment: no position attribute supported for div in email clients..any other option??may be from table

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with feature support in email clients, but couldn't you have a `div` where this image is set as the `background-image`, and use `position:relative` to place the other div where you need it?

Comment: no position attribute supported for div in email clients..any other option??may be from table